# Downloading Google Charts Image to ImageView

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, picasso

So I'm using the Picasso library to put web images into my ImageView. However, I have this one file on Google Charts, which when opened in Chrome is an image, yet has no extension:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=LG-80294959&choe=UTF-8

I've also tried appending &.png to the URL and Picasso still fails to download the image. However, once I change the URL to something static (such as https://puu.sh/us6td/3dda131f46.png), the image is displayed just fine.

How can I circumvent this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following permissions set in your AndroidManifest.xml to access the internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In MainActivity.java:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

// show The Image in a ImageView
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
            .execute("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=LG-80294959&choe=UTF-8");

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Enjoy it!

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problems for the Google Charts.

Another URL of the same format doesn't seem to work, however: https://hackforums.net/captcha.php?imagehash=de186516263983d99bdc789691675ae7

It throws: "java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()" due to a "java.lang.NullPointerException" of the InputStream. Any ideas why?